# How to place widgets where i want in stetic editor for GTK#

Tags: user-interface, gtk#

I Creating GUI i stetic editor (GTK#) for MonoDevelop. And i can't place widgets (like buttons) where i want. When i put button in to GUI it take all place on screen and i cant change it and place on correct spot, how to do that? I looking for something like layout manager in Java Swing.

So what component i need to use to create correct background for placing widgets?

```
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();

}
```

This is how look my MainWidows constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Gtk+ layout is done using containers. Basically you need to place containers (`Gtk.HBox`, `Gtk.VBox`, ...) inside containers and then fill them with widgets. You can set the padding, the spacing between siblings, the relative weight when expanding, how to expand/fill and so on. Very Css-ish.

Apart from simple boxes, you have some containers that are a bit more specialized and allow you to place child widgets in special ways. For example `Gtk.Table` let you arrange children spanning rows and columns of the table. `Gtk.Fixed` allow for absolute positioning of children.

If you're using MonoDevelop look at the toolbox and experiment with the **Containers** widgets.